# Install v142 to build using the v142 build tools

Tags: c++, opengl, visual-studio-2015

I am using Visual Studio 2015 (I know it is old, I want to use it though). I want to run this sln called Assimp.sln. When I open it, it says that I need t install v124 build tools, but I don't know how. Is it true that I can only do it on VS 17 and 19? I am sure it isn't because Ben, from the Udemy course on OpenGL graphics, made it work on VS 2015. Could someone help? I won't put much on this question because I didn't make the solution anyways.

Answer (score 3):

Removing the following environment variable fixed my issue

VCTargetsPath

C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio 2015 comes with the `v140` Platform Toolset which is the C++ Compiler 19.0. If you had VS 2013 installed side-by-side, the VS 2015 IDE would show `v120` Platform Toolset as an option.

Visual Studio 2019 comes with the `v142` Platform Toolset which is the C++ Compiler 19.2. You can install `v141` Platform Toolset which is the VS 2017 version of the C++ Compiler 19.1. VS 2019 *also* includes a `v120` Platform Toolset option for VS 2015 projects. For VS 2017 / VS 2019, these older platform toolsets are offered as 'optional components' instead of having to install the older versions of the product.

```
VS 2010   Platform Toolset v100    Visual C++ 16.0
VS 2012   Platform Toolset v110    Visual C++ 17.0
VS 2013   Platform Toolset v120    Visual C++ 18.0
VS 2015   Platform Toolset v140    Visual C++ 19.0
VS 2017   Platform Toolset v141    Visual C++ 19.1
VS 2019   Platform Toolset v142    Visual C++ 19.2
```

**TL;DR:** Upgrade to Visual Studio 2019. You may qualify for the [Community edition](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/community/) license so you can consider that as well.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't understand how Ben did it on VS 2015. I was expecting something like how to install the v142 build tools on VS 2015, but you're just saying that I should upgrade. Also, is it fine if I open assimp.sln in a different version of VS, and then I use it in my VS 2015 project?

Comment: also, i can't believe that my question didn't get closed, and instead it recieved an answer.

Comment: i made the project on VS 2015, and I want to do it on VS 2015, but, I can't get assimp to work. and, if you give an answer, you should try watching yourself (ok, it's a udemy course that you pay for, but, it could be useful for you yourself to follow).